# Unselectable html in tinymce editor3.x?

Tags: tinymce-3

```
<div style="-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;"></div>
```

Above style is  working fine in html, but when i used this in TinyMce editor this is not working.

Comment: Maybe a little late, but if you are attempting this in Google Chrome, this may very well be [a browser-related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37913629/521032) with `user-select` inside a `contenteditable` div.