# Chrome appears to ignore user-select in a contenteditable div

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, contenteditable

I need to make it so some elements inside a `contenteditable` div are not selectable, so that the user will skip over them if they try to move the caret around where they are.

The obvious solution appears to be to style these sections using `user-select: none`. This works really well in Firefox, but, unfortunately, completely fails in Google Chrome.

```css
.ok {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
     -moz-user-select: text;
      -ms-user-select: text;
          user-select: text;
}

.nope {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" readonly>
  <span class="ok">One</span><span class="nope">Two</span><span class="ok">Three</span>
  <div class="nope">
    <span class="ok">One</span><span class="nope">Two</span><span class="ok">Three</span>
  </div>
  <span class="nope">One</span><span class="ok">Two</span><span class="nope">Three</span>
  <div class="nope">
    <span class="nope">One</span><span class="ok">Two</span><span class="nope">Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to get this to work in Chrome as well, or is it an insurmountable limitation?

Comment: for `input[type=text]` too and i imagine for other `input[types]` too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've run into this issue as well and have found a decent work around. It's not pretty but it can often get the job done.

If you add `contenteditable="false"` along with `user-select:none;` then Chrome will process the CSS rule correctly. Those elements will no longer be selectable.

The main disadvantage to this (besides having to modify the HTML) is that if one adds `contenteditable="false"` on a wrapper div then all its children become non-editable as well. You can further nest another `contenteditable="true"`, which will allow the nested content to be editable, but then one cannot select from the nested content to the outside content.

Ultimately, a correct implementation of the CSS rule in Chrome when contenteditable is enabled would be the best solution. (Could be intentional due to user-select spec, see comment below)

Example of solution using `contenteditable="false"` (not on wrapper divs).

```css
.ok {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.nope {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" readonly>
  <span class="ok">One</span>
  <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">Two</span>
  <span class="ok">Three</span>
  <div>
    <span class="ok">One</span>
    <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">Two</span>
    <span class="ok">Three</span>
  </div>
  <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">One</span>
  <span class="ok">Two</span>
  <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">Three</span>
  <div>
    <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">One</span>
    <span class="ok">Two</span>
    <span class="nope" contenteditable="false">Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Insight into why Chrome may ignore `user-select:none;` on editable... From the spec: _If the element is an editable element, the computed value is `contain`_

Comment: The development has taken another path (using a different editor), so it'd be difficult for me to test whether this works... I accept the answer until further notice.

Comment: This is a good start, but unfortunately, you can still delete the entire `<span class="nope" contenteditable="false">Two</span>` section from the left or right, just not its contents individually. This is probably a problematic edge case for most use cases

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
```

The `user-modify` property is supposedly on it's way out - at least for mozilla ([mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-modify)) and instead they propose to use `contenteditable` attribute... which is clearly not ready as a replacement.

For those having problems with the element(s) being selected whole as a part of a selection range that starts from the surrounding element - setting `user-select: none` on the outside element will solve this problem.