# How to set cursor position in contenteditable div without random span

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have two divs inside a contenteditable div, like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="mainDiv">
  <div id="div1">Line 1</div>
  <div id="div2">Line 2</div>
</div>
```

and I want to set the cursor at the beginning of "Line 2". I use the following code to do so

```
function setCursorAtInnerDiv(mainDiv, div2) {
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(div2);
  range.collapse(true);
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

When I look at the elements, the divs look just as shown above all the way until this code returns.

Then suddenly the HTML gets messed up like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="mainDiv">
  <div id="div1">Line 1</div>
  <span style="font-family: -apple-system...; font-size: 1rem;">Line 2</span>
</div>
```

(where "..." is a bunch of fonts listed). The end result is that instead of a 'div', I know have a 'span', which means Line 2 does not start on its own line.

Why did my div turn into a span (with a bunch of font stuff in it)? Did Chrome do that? I sure didn't.

How can I set the cursor position without messing up my lines? Is there a "don't ruin my html" flag?

Comment: Are you calling function with both params or just `div2`? It doesn't look like you need the first param `mainDiv, `.

Comment: Huh. If I wrap the "selection.addRange(range)" in a Timeout (even with 0ms), then it works fine and doesn't ruin the <div> with <spans>. Whatever.

Comment: I think I recall there's a bug in Chrome when handling `selection` when pertaining to `contenteditable` and/or `<textarea>`...here it [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913629/chrome-appears-to-ignore-user-select-in-a-contenteditable-div)